# Median filter_invalid syntax

Tags: pyqgis, filter, scipy

I would like to apply a median filter to an image (.tif).
I looked for solutions in QGIS, and found a lot of possibilities to apply a mean filter, but none for a median filter.
So I decided to try something with the python console in QGIS, but I am quite new at this... The code I have for now is the Following one :

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import ndimage

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im_med = ndimage.median_filter(2018blackandwhite, 3)
```

2018blackandwhite being the image I want to apply the median filter on.

The error I am getting is "SyntxError : invalid syntax". I have tried to add the extension .tif after the name of the image, and I have the same error.

I am quite lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input to ndimage should be an numpy array, you are providing an undefined variable.

Try something like (from [Raster layer to numpy Array](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Raster-layer-to-numpy-array-td5055679.html)):

```
import gdal
from scipy import ndimage
rasterPath = r"C:\somfolder\s1milj.tif" #Or you could fetch the path from the layer in QGIS using some code
ds = gdal.Open(rasterPath) 
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
   
im_med = ndimage.median_filter(band1, 3)
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks for your help, I didn't know I need to kind of "convert" my image, because based on the tutorials I saw (https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/auto_examples/plot_denoising.html), it seems like they didn't do it.